# How to change the bibliographystyle .bst file (TexStudio)

Tags: miktex, texstudio, abbrvnat.bst, tds

I would like to change the **bibliographystyle** manually in my .tex file. 
 
I use **TexStudio**. 
 
I have already found out that the changes have to be made in the **.bst file** and wanted to save it in the appropriate folder of MikTex, but I was denied that, even the assignment of another folder in MiKTex was not possible, then came always the message it is not **TDS compatible**.
 
Can you help me?

Comment: You can save the bst file in the same folder as your tex file.

Comment: I tried, but TeXStudio gave me the error:  "I couldn't open style file"

Comment: How are you using it? It is not like a package (sty file), so don't use `\usepackage{}` on it.

Comment: It was a typo ... 

Sigur thank you!

Comment: Another question: I want to change the point between Authors, Title, Journal, ... to a comma at each position. Where can I do this?